# Why some worker nodes cost more CPU for system during running Spark application?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, cpu-usage

I have 1 master node and 4 worker nodes. I set up the cluster using Ambari and all monitoring metrics are collected from its dashboard. Spark on the top of Hadoop, so I have got YARN and HDFS. I run a very simple word count script and found that one of the worker nodes did the most job. The word count job is divided into 149 tasks. 98 tasks are done by one node.

Here is my code for counting words

```
 val file = sc.textFile("/data/2gdata.txt") //read file from HDFS
 val counts = file.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
 counts.collect*
```

This picture illustrates the events timeline and CPU usage for each worder nodes

[image: This picture illustrates the events timeline and CPU usage for each worder nodes]

Aggregated Metrics by Executor are shown here

[image: Aggregated Metrics by Executor are shown here]

Each task has same size of input file. I assume they would spend similar time such as around 30 seconds to count word in the piece of input file. Some tasks spent more than 10 minutes.

I realized those nodes doing less job cost more CPU for system operation as shown in blue area in the first graph. The worker did more tasks and cost more CPU for user (application).

I am wondering what kinds of system operations required for a Spark application. Why three of worker nodes cost more CPU for system? I also enabled *spark.speculation*, but those stragglers will be killed after 10 minutes and performance didn't get better. Moreover, those stragglers are node_local, so I assume this issue is not related to HDFS replication. (There are 3 replications under the rack.)

Thank you very much.

Comment: Some common, more frequent words such as `a`, `and`, `the`, etc may be collected onto a single task. You may look into removing "stop words" to see if that reduced the load

Comment: Thank you, that is a good point. Do you have idea about system cost? Those tasks consumed a lot of CPU for system. In my opinion, even with more frequent words, CPU should be consumed for user (orange area in the graph) instead of system (blue in the graph). The last node CPU usage graph is same as what I expect.

Comment: I'm not sure, but your data is heavily skewed. Look at the input size column

Answer (score 0):

Even the input file size is same for each task, during the shuffle and reduce phase, some task might process more data than other tasks, data skewing may cause more CPU costs.

You can repartitioning the data in between may improve the performance.

Comment: Based on my understanding, I though CPU used for processing data would be counted as user usage not the system usage. In my opinion, system CPU usage would be CPU cost in the operating system kernel. I am using Ubuntu system. Is it possible to give me an example how the application works on the operating system side? Or what kind of operation would cost CPU as system usage? I really appreciate your suggestion!